# How to access shared folders in Ubuntu VM(Oracle Virtualbox) and link them to the home folder

Tags: virtualbox

I have configured a shared folder between the Windows host and Ubuntu guest. The folder mounts at start up but its empty(It also has a padlock sign.). I have to run the command  below to access its content(the padlock sign disappears).

```
  sudo mount.vboxsf media ~/media
```

How can i configure it to be run automatically at start up. I've tried adding to the start up programs but nothing happens. 
 Am new to Linux so try to put your answer in a layman's language.
Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this :

http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Answer (score 49):

The mounted share folder belongs to the `vboxsf` user. You, as a user, were not added to the `vboxsf` group. To allow access to the shared folders permanently, copy and paste this command in a Terminal window:

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a $USER
```

`$USER` will be replaced with your username. This command appends the user `<username>` to the *vboxsf* group, which is the owner of the shared folders (found in `/media/...` on the Ubuntu box).

You won't need to run a script at startup once you own the mounted shared folder.

But you will most likely need to logout and on again (or restart).

Comment: For a few other tips about Ubuntu on a VirtualBox (Mac) see: [blog entry] (http://aboutfoto.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/of-ggobi-macports-and-r/).

Comment: It doesn't work. I had tried a similar thing earlier with this code: I don't know if its the same thing.

         `sudo adduser <username> vboxsf`

Comment: Strange... On the box I'm using the shared folder appears as /media/sf_shared, and if I look at its permissions with ls -l I get: `drwxrwx---  2 root vboxsf 4096 Apr  3 18:47 sf_shared`. Please check with the `users-admin` program if your user name is indeed in the vboxsf group (there is a button called Manage Groups and look at Properties of the vboxsf group).

Comment: Am so sorry. The shared folder with the contents does appear in the media folder. What i wanted was for it to appear in my home folder with the contents. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: No problem. If you have writing access on the shared folder, that's fine. You can create a symbolic link in your home or Documents folder for easy access. In Terminal (assuming that you are in the directory where you want the link to appear) do: `ln -s /media/sf_shared/ name_of_link`. Replace `sf_shared` with the actual name of the shared directory and `name_of_link` with whatever you want. Alternatively, you can just drag the folder in Nautilus to the right navigation area and it will create an easy to access link.

Comment: Thank you. Used the terminal option. Linux is haha,fun to learn. Thank you @Cocofifi.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found a working solution. I have little experience with askubuntu, but if possible, it would be probably good to change the title of your question, so that people looking for the same kind of information could benefit from the discussion.

Comment: How can i do that? Am also new to askbuntu.

Comment: Me too :-) I think there is an edit link for the original question that allows you to change the title. Best regards.

Comment: I've edited it.I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey @Njihia its probably better to put all this comments (steps) in an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) and accept your answer. This way someone doesn't have to look through all this comments

Comment: Ok. A good suggestion. In fact i was looking for something like "accept as solution". I'll do that. Thanks @Mojo706.

Comment: ! Restart virtual machine once you done this.

Answer (score 6):

So here is how to access your shared folders on Ubuntu VM(Oracle Virtualbox). Am assuming you have already enabled auto-mount while you were adding the folder.
Open the terminal and type.

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a $USER
```

This command appends the current user to the vboxsf group, which is the owner of the shared folders (found in /media/ on the Ubuntu box). Confirm from your media folder if the shared folders are present. They're usually named "sf_name-of-shared-folder".
For quick access, you may want to create a link to the shared folders in the home folder.
In Terminal (assuming that you are in the directory where you want the link to appear and that you've enabled the Nautilus plugin that gives you the context menu option ) do:

```
ln -s /media/sf_shared/ name_of_link.
```

Replace sf_shared with the actual name of the shared directory and name_of_link with whatever you want. However the name-of-link shouldn't exist in the directory where you want to create the link(That is there should be no folder or file with that name). Alternatively, you can just drag the folder in Nautilus to the right navigation area and it will create an easy to access link.

Comment: Possibly one needs to log off/log on again before being able to access the shared folder.

Comment: ^^ YES, I had to logoff/logon for this to work